# ANTLR error：no viable alternative at input '<EOF>'. How to fix it?

Tags: antlr

I am a new leaner to ANTLR. And met a same error when using ANTLR to compile 2 JAVA files. Trees look good with no defect leaves. I cannot find any clue of the root cause of this error.
The version of ANTLR I used is 'ANTLR 4'.
Anybody knows how to fix it? Thanks in advance!

1) ANTLR file is test.g4 as below,

```
grammar test;

// Syntax Specification ==> Context-free Grammar 
pa1: 
     mainClass aClass*;

mainClass: 
    classDeclaration '{' mainDeclaration ('{'body'}'|'{''{'body'}''}') '}';

mainDeclaration:
    'public' 'static' 'void' 'main' '(' 'String''['']' ID ')';

aClass:
    classDeclaration '{' body '}';

classDeclaration:
    'class' ID;

aMethod:
    methodDeclaration'{'body'}';

methodDeclaration:
    type ID'('parameterList')';

body:
    (varDeclaration|statement|expression|aMethod)*;

varDeclaration:
    type ID ';' ;

statement: 
    (ID|arrayElement) '=' (NUM|ID|string|aChar|('new' type)? arrayElement|'new' (type|ID) '('')'|aCall|mathExpression)';';  //(ID|arrayElement) '=' (NUM|ID|string|aChar|arrayElement|aCall|mathExpression|booleanExpression)';';

string:
    '"' .*? '"';

aChar:
    '\''(.?|'+'|'-')'\'';

expression: 
    ID';'|whileExpression|ifExpression|sysPrintExpression|returnExpression;

ifExpression:
    'if''('booleanExpression')' ((varDeclaration|statement|expression)*|'{'(varDeclaration|statement|expression)*'}')
    ('else''if''('booleanExpression')' ((varDeclaration|statement|expression)*|'{'(varDeclaration|statement|expression)*'}'))?  
    ('else'((varDeclaration|statement|expression)*|'{'(varDeclaration|statement|expression)*'}'))?;

whileExpression: 
    'while''('booleanExpression')' '{'(varDeclaration|statement|expression)*'}';

sysPrintExpression: 
    'System''.''out''.''println''('(NUM|arrayElement|aCall)')'';';

returnExpression: 
    'return'(NUM|ID)';';

compExpression: 
    (ID|NUM|mathExpression) COMPOPERATOR (ID|NUM|'('mathExpression')'|'('ID')');

mathExpression: 
    (ID|NUM) (PLUS|MINUS|MULT|DIV)(ID|NUM|('('ID'.'ID'('parameterList')'')'));  

singleBooleanExpression: 
    '!'?('('compExpression')'|compExpression|aCall|ID);//(LOGICALOPERATOR('!'?(compExpression|aCall|ID|string|aChar)))?;    

doubleBooleanExpression: 
    '(''!'?('('compExpression')'|compExpression|aCall|ID)')'LOGICALOPERATOR('(''!'?(compExpression|aCall|ID|string|aChar)')');

booleanExpression:
    singleBooleanExpression|doubleBooleanExpression;    

aCall: 
    (ID|'new'? ID '('')')calling|'('(ID|ID'('')')calling')'calling;

calling:
    '.'(ID('('parameterList')')?);  

parameterList: 
    (NUM|type? ID|aChar|string|mathExpression|aCall)?(','(NUM|type? ID|aChar|mathExpression))*;

arrayElement: 
    ID?'['(ID|NUM)']';

type: 
    'int''['']'|'boolean'|'int'|'char'|ID;  

// Lexer Specification ==> Regular Expressions  
NUM: ('0' | [1-9][0-9]*);
ID: [a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]*;
PLUS : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
MULT : '*' ;
DIV : '/';
COMPOPERATOR: '<'|'>'; 
LOGICALOPERATOR: '=='|'||'|'&&';
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n]+  -> skip; 
COMMENT: ('/*'.*?'*/'|'//'~[\r\n|\r|\n]*) -> skip;
```

2) JAVA file1 is MyChar.java as below,

```
class MyChar{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        {
            System.out.println(new CharEditor().whichIsSmaller('a', 'c'));
            System.out.println(new CharEditor().whichIsSmaller('a', 'A'));
            System.out.println(new CharEditor().whichIsSmaller('1', 'd'));
            System.out.println(new CharEditor().whichIsSmaller('-', '+'));
            // System.out.println("There are total " + new MyChar().countFromCharToChar('a', 'z', true) + " characters in between a and z");
            System.out.println(new CharEditor().countChars("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.", 'c'));
        }
    }
}

class CharEditor {

    char whichIsSmaller(char firstChar, char secondChar){
        char returnChar;

        if(secondChar < firstChar) //the comparison is based on the character's ASCII code
        returnChar = firstChar;
        else
        returnChar = secondChar;
        return returnChar;
    }

    int countChars(String str, char c){
        int n;
        int sz;
        char c1;
        int counter;

        counter = 0;

        sz = str.length();
        n = 0;
        while ( n < sz ) {
            c1 = str.charAt(n);
            if ( c1 == c) {
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
            n = n + 1;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}
```

3)JAVA file2 is MyString.java as below,

```
class MyString{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        {
            System.out.println(new StringEditor().removeSpace("Hello World And Happy Coding"));
            System.out.println(new StringEditor().containsChar("Hello World And Happy Coding", 'd'));
            System.out.println(new StringEditor().containsChar("Hello World And Happy Coding", 'b'));
        }
    }
}

class StringEditor {
    String removeSpace(String str) {
        String toReturn;
        int n;
        int sz;
        char c;

        toReturn = "";
        sz = str.length();
        n = 0;
        while ( n < sz ) {
            c = str.charAt(n);
            if ( c == ' ') {

            } else {
                toReturn = toReturn + c;
            }
            n = n+1;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    boolean containsChar(String str, char c) {
        int n;
        int sz;
        char c1;

        boolean toReturn;

        toReturn = false;

        sz = str.length();
        n = 0;
        while ( n < sz ) {
            c1 = str.charAt(n);
            if ( c1 == c) {
                toReturn = true;
                break;
            }
            n = n+1;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Concerning file 1, the grammar is unable to parse line 26 `int countChars(String str, char c){` because `String` is missing in rule `type`. Also move `==`from `LOGICALOPERATOR` to `COMPOPERATOR`.

Comment: Thanks Bernard! It works for file 1. And enlightened by you, I solved it for file 2 also.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that you have solved the problem for file 2, I nevertheless post the answer I was working on.

In case of problem, the first thing to do is displaying the tokens to see how the lexer has interpreted the input. It's often not what we believe. With file 2 :

```
$ grun Question question -tokens -diagnostics input2.text 
...
[@131,652:653='if',<'if'>,23:12]
[@132,655:655='(',<'('>,23:15]
[@133,657:657='c',<ID>,23:17]
[@134,659:660='==',<COMP_OPERATOR>,23:19]
[@135,662:662=''',<'''>,23:22]
[@136,664:664=''',<'''>,23:24]
[@137,665:665=')',<')'>,23:25]
[@138,667:667='{',<'{'>,23:27]
[@139,682:682='}',<'}'>,25:12]
```

shows that in the statement 23

```
    if ( c == ' ') {
```

the single space character is interpreted as two separate `'`, not by rule

```
aChar:
    '\'' ( .? | '+' | '-' ) '\'';
```

because the apostrophe is implicitly defined as a token in this parser rule `aChar`, the space is thrown away by

```
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n]+  -> skip;
```

and no lexer rule forces the lexer to consider `' '` as a whole. That's why I have changed parser rule `aChar` to lexer rule

```
A_CHAR : '\'' ( '+' | '-' | .? ) '\'' ;
```

Now the tokens are correct :

```
[@127,652:653='if',<'if'>,23:12]
[@128,655:655='(',<'('>,23:15]
[@129,657:657='c',<ID>,23:17]
[@130,659:660='==',<COMP_OPERATOR>,23:19]
[@131,662:664='' '',<A_CHAR>,23:22]
[@132,665:665=')',<')'>,23:25]
```

Also note that with the `string` parser rule, each word of `"Lorem ipsum dolor sit met ..."` is interpreted as an `ID`, whereas with the lexer rule `STRING` the whole sentence is captured in a single token.

Another improvement is applying the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself). For example in `ifExpression`, the expression `(varDeclaration|statement|expression)` is repeated 6 times. This can be reduced using subrules.

Thus the grammar could be :

```
grammar Question;

question
@init {System.out.println("Question last update 1803");}

// Syntax Specification ==> Context-free Grammar 
    :   mainClass aClass*;

mainClass
    :   classDeclaration '{' mainDeclaration declaration_block '}';

mainDeclaration:
    'public' 'static' 'void' 'main' '(' 'String' '[' ']' ID ')';

aClass:
    classDeclaration declaration_block ;

classDeclaration:
    'class' ID;

aMethod:
    methodDeclaration declaration_block ;

methodDeclaration:
    type ID parameterList ;

declaration_block
    :   '{' declarattion_body* '}'
    |   '{' declaration_block '}'
    ;

declarattion_body
    :   statement
    |   aMethod
    ;

statement_block
    :   '{' statement* '}'
    ;

statement
    :   varDeclaration
    |   assignment
    |   statement_expression
    ;

varDeclaration:
    type ID ';' ;

assignment: 
    (ID|arrayElement) '=' (NUM|ID|STRING|A_CHAR|('new' type)? arrayElement|'new' (type|ID) '('')'|aCall|mathExpression)';';  //(ID|arrayElement) '=' (NUM|ID|STRING|A_CHAR|arrayElement|aCall|mathExpression|booleanExpression)';';

statement_expression
    :   ID ';'
    |   whileExpression
    |   ifExpression
    |   sysPrintExpression
    |   returnExpression
    ;

ifExpression
    :   'if' '(' booleanExpression ')' statement_if
        ( 'else' 'if' '(' booleanExpression ')' statement_if )?  
        ( 'else' statement_if )?
    ;

statement_if
    :   statement*
    |   statement_block
    ;

whileExpression
    :   'while' '(' booleanExpression ')' statement_block
    ;

sysPrintExpression: 
    'System''.''out''.''println''('(NUM|arrayElement|aCall)')'';';

returnExpression: 
    'return'(NUM|ID)';';

compExpression
    :   ( ID | NUM | mathExpression ) COMP_OPERATOR ( ID | NUM | A_CHAR | '(' mathExpression ')' | '(' ID ')' ) ;

mathExpression: 
    (ID|NUM) (PLUS|MINUS|MULT|DIV) ( ID | NUM | ( '(' ID '.' ID parameterList ')' ));  

singleBooleanExpression
    :   '!'? ( '(' compExpression ')' | compExpression | aCall | ID ) ; //(LOGICAL_OPERATOR('!'?(compExpression|aCall|ID|STRING|A_CHAR)))?;    

doubleBooleanExpression: 
    '(''!'?('('compExpression')'|compExpression|aCall|ID)')'LOGICAL_OPERATOR('(''!'?(compExpression|aCall|ID|STRING|A_CHAR)')');

booleanExpression
    :   singleBooleanExpression
    |   doubleBooleanExpression
    ;

aCall: 
    (ID|'new'? ID '('')')calling|'('(ID|ID'('')')calling')'calling;

calling:
    '.' ( ID ( parameterList )? ) ;  

parameterList
    :   '('  
        ( NUM | type? ID | A_CHAR | STRING | mathExpression | aCall )? 
        ( ',' ( NUM | type? ID | A_CHAR | mathExpression ) )*
        ')'
    ;

arrayElement: 
    ID? '[' ( ID | NUM ) ']' ;

type
    :   'int' '[' ']'
    |   'boolean'
    |   'int'
    |   'char'
    |   'String' // <----- added
    |   ID;  

// Lexer Specification ==> Regular Expressions  
NUM   : '0' | [1-9][0-9]* ;
ID    : [a-zA-Z_][0-9a-zA-Z_]* ;
PLUS  : '+' ;
MINUS : '-' ;
MULT  : '*' ;
DIV   : '/' ;
COMP_OPERATOR    : '<' | '>' | '==' ;  // <----- changed
LOGICAL_OPERATOR : '||' | '&&' ; // <----- changed
STRING : '"' .*? '"' ;
A_CHAR : '\'' ( '+' | '-' | .? ) '\'' ;
WHITESPACE: [ \t\r\n]+  -> skip; 
//COMMENT: ('/*'.*?'*/'|'//'~[\r\n|\r|\n]*) -> skip; 
/*
warning(180): Question.g4:103:27: chars "" used multiple times in set [\r\n|\r|\n]
warning(180): Question.g4:103:27: chars "|" used multiple times in set [\r\n|\r|\n]
warning(180): Question.g4:103:27: chars "
" used multiple times in set [\r\n|\r|\n]
*/
COMMENT      : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip ;
LINE_COMMENT : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip;
```

But it works only on the two posted files. With this one :

```
class MyString{
    public static void main(String[] a){
        {
        }
    }
}

public class test {
    public static class UnderlineListener extends BaseErrorListener {
    }
}
```

it doesn't work :

```
$ grun Question question input3.text 
Question last update 1803
line 8:0 extraneous input 'public' expecting {<EOF>, 'class'}
line 9:1 no viable alternative at input '{public'
line 9:39 mismatched input 'extends' expecting '{'
```

Writing a grammar for an existing language is exciting but difficult. There are ready to go Java grammars [from the Antlr site](http://www.antlr.org)
-> Download

-> Source Repository

Everything's up at [github](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4)

-> Additional grammars

[This repository](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4)